# How to disable cache in CRUD application AngularJS + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have problem with cache in Internet Explorer. In Chrome everything works fine. When I try to add item in my application then data doesn't refresh. I have to press Ctrl+R to refresh data.

I'm using:

- NodeJS / express (backend)
- AngularJS (frontend)
- Jade (view engine)
- MongoDB / mongoose (database)

Jade view:

```
form(name="AddPartner") 
     .col-md-4
          |Name: 
          input.form-control(type='text', name='name' ng-model="dataPartner.name")
```

Script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){    

$scope.loadPartnersData = function () {
$http.get("/main/partner-list").then(function(result) {
$scope.partnerList = result.data.partnerList;
});
};
$scope.loadPartnersData();


$scope.addPartner = function(data) {
$http.post(addPartner, data)
.then(function(response) {
console.log(response);
});
$scope.loadPartnersData();
window.alert("Done!");
};
```

My backend:

```
router.get('/partner-list', function (req, res) {
    Partner.find({}, function (err, partnerList) {
        if (err) throw err;

        res.json({ partnerList: partnerList });
    });
});


router.post('/addPartner', function (req, res) {
    new Partner({ name : req.body.name, shared : req.body.shared }).save(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `$scope.digest()` explicitly after adding data to the scope.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Write your response like `res.json(response);` and also move your `$scope.loadPartnersData();` call inside the `then` portion of your promise. ;)